# i686-w64-mingw32-g++ Cannot link .obj produced by JWASM

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, mingw, jwasm

Hello I'm trying to compile this program written for MASM:

```
.686
.xmm
.model flat, stdcall
OPTION CaseMap:None

include ../masm32/libs/windows.inc
include ../masm32/libs/kernel32.inc
includelib ../masm32/libs/kernel32.lib
include ../masm32/libs/user32.inc
includelib ../masm32/libs/user32.lib
includelib ../masm32/libs/msvcrt.lib

EXTERN printf:PROC

.data
    string1 db "Prova Prova Prova",0


.code

main PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    mov eax, offset string1
    push eax

    call printf

    pop ebp
    ret

main ENDP
    END
```

I'm making the object file with:
`jwasm -coff printf.asm`

but when I try to compile with:
`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -m32 printf.o`

I get the following error:

> Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:../masm32/libs/kernel32.lib ' unrecognized Warning: .drectve` -defaultlib:../masm32/libs/user32.lib
> ' unrecognized Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
> /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld:
> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):
> in function `main': ./build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to` WinMain@16' collect2: error: ld returned 1
> exit status

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix the MASM32 libraries with G++'s own version of the libraries. G++ probably doesn't seem to support the `includelib` entries in the object file. The C library has C calling convention so you will want `.model flat, C` instead of stdcall and you will have to remove the values pushed on the stack after calling `printf`. As well comment out the `includelib` lines (keep the `include` lines as is).

Comment: It should be noted that JWASM isn't the problem, it is that the linker LD that GCC/G++ uses is not the Microsoft linker which can properly parse the includelib info that was embedded in the object file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it start now but how can I pass the string to print to "printf" if I need to remove "push eax"? I though "push eax" was needed to pass the string as a parameter to printf. Thank you

Comment: OK I made it works with the "push eax", I was missing "invoke ExitProcess, 0" at the end. Thank you!

Comment: You still push parameters on the stack for the `printf` call, but when you finish you pop them off or you just add the number of bytes pushed back to ESP. So you could do `add esp, 4` after the call to `printf` since you pushed 4 bytes on the stack when you pushed EAX. If you had added `add ESP, 4` the `ret` should have worked without calling ExitProcess.

Comment: If you pushed 2 parameters on you would do `add esp, 8` after the call to `printf` to rebalance the stack and get rid of the parameters.